# Diffie Hellman c# implementation

Tags: cryptography, .net, key-exchange

For a test project I have tried to implement the (famous) Diffie Hellman algorithm for safe key exchange.

Now I have written this in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DiffieHellman.Cryptology
{
    public static class CentralAuthority
    {
        private static readonly List<Int32> _primes = new List<Int32>();

        public static void CreatePrimeTable()
        {
            const Int32 topNumber = Int32.MaxValue / 2;
            BitArray numbers = new BitArray(topNumber, true);

            for (Int32 i = 2; i < topNumber; i++)
            {
                if (!numbers[i])
                    continue;

                for (Int32 j = i * 2; j < topNumber; j += i)
                    numbers[j] = false;
            }

            for (Int32 i = 1; i < topNumber; i++)
            {
                if (numbers[i])
                    _primes.Add(i);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generate a random Prime Number.
        /// </summary>
        public static Int32 GeneratePrime()
        {
            Int32 p = Randomizer.GetRandom(1, _primes.Count);
            return _primes[p];
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generate a random base integer (g) less than the prime
        /// </summary>
        public static Int32 GenerateBase(
            Int32 prime)
        {
            return Randomizer.GetRandom(1, prime - 1);
        }
    }
}




using System;

namespace DiffieHellman.Cryptology
{
    public class CaDiffieHellman
    {
        public Int64 Key { get; private set; }
        public Int32 Prime { get; private set; }
        public Int32 Generator { get; private set; }
        public Int64 ExponentiationY { get; private set; }
        private Int32 _privateX;

        public void GenerateParameters(
            Int32 prime = 0,
            Int32 generator = 0)
        {
            if (prime < 1 && generator < 1)
            {
                prime = CentralAuthority.GeneratePrime();
                generator = CentralAuthority.GenerateBase(prime);
            }

            if (prime <= generator - 1)
                return;

            Prime = prime;
            Generator = generator;
            _privateX = Randomizer.GetRandom(1, Prime - 1);

            Int64 xor = Generator ^ _privateX;
            while (xor > Prime - 1
                || xor == _privateX)
            {
                _privateX = Randomizer.GetRandom(1, Prime - 1);
                xor = Generator ^ _privateX;
            }

            ExponentiationY = (xor) % Prime;
        }

        public void GenerateKey(
            Int64 exponentiationYOther)
        {
            Key = (exponentiationYOther ^ _privateX) % Prime;
        }
    }
}



using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace DiffieHellman.Cryptology
{
    public static class Randomizer
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Real random generator
        /// Slower then Random().Next()!
        /// </summary>
        public static Int32 GetRandom(
            Int32 max)
        {
            return GetRandom(0, max);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Real random generator
        /// Slower than Random().Next()!
        /// </summary>
        public static Int32 GetRandom(
            Int32 min,
            Int32 max)
        {
            // Start a slower but more acurate randomizer service
            RNGCryptoServiceProvider rngCryptoServiceProvider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
            Byte[] randomBytes = new Byte[4];
            rngCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes(randomBytes);
            Int32 seed = BitConverter.ToInt32(randomBytes, 0);

            return new Random(seed).Next(min, max);
        }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using DiffieHellman.Cryptology;

namespace DiffieHellman
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static readonly CaDiffieHellman _caDiffieHellmanServer = new CaDiffieHellman();
        private static readonly CaDiffieHellman _caDiffieHellmanClient = new CaDiffieHellman();

        static void Main()
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            CentralAuthority.CreatePrimeTable();
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Create Prime Table: {0}ms", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (Int32 i = 0; i < Int32.MaxValue; i++)
            {
                // Generate random prime and generator at server
                _caDiffieHellmanServer.GenerateParameters();

                // Send prime and generator to client
                _caDiffieHellmanClient.GenerateParameters(_caDiffieHellmanServer.Prime, _caDiffieHellmanServer.Generator);

                // Calculate the key
                _caDiffieHellmanServer.GenerateKey(_caDiffieHellmanClient.ExponentiationY);

                // Calculate the key
                _caDiffieHellmanClient.GenerateKey(_caDiffieHellmanServer.ExponentiationY);

                if (_caDiffieHellmanServer.Key != _caDiffieHellmanClient.Key)
                    Console.WriteLine("Error ({0}): wrong key", i);

                if (_caDiffieHellmanServer.Key == 0 || _caDiffieHellmanClient.Key == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("Error ({0}): key 0", i);

                if (i % 10000 == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("Progress: {0}, {1}ms, {2}", i, stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds, _caDiffieHellmanServer.Key);
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Loop: {0}ms", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Now my main concern is that I did not use the standard formula: g pow(a) mod p = A, but g XOR a mod p. The pow(a) does not work if it goes outside the int64 value.

Is this a safety concern?

This implementation has only 1 bug: when both parties generate the same privateX, it will fail, but with the large amount of base numbers generated this only happens once in about 50 million times.

I would like to discuss the strength of this method and potential pitfalls!

Thanks!

Comment: I'll let a cryptography expert explain just how this is broken, but as a basic principle, you **never ever change a cryptographic algorithm** unless you have a degree in cryptography. (And if you do you don't start using your new version until it's had serious peer review.) Here, you need to implement [modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation).

Comment: and for speed concerns, don't use C# for this kind algo which can have a lot of iterations. C++ or C would be preferred... You also better use some already existing code or lib for that, search for open stuff, lots of chance you will find something better and safer.

Comment: "you never ever change a cryptographic algorithm" - People implement cryptographic algorithms for educational purposes too you know.

Comment: @jokoon I've implemented ECC in C# and it's not much slower than equivalent standard C code. C only pulls significantly ahead once you use Int128 language extensions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you implemented is *not* Diffie-Hellman, and has no strength at all. You are being confused with the use of the '`^`' character.

In C-like programming languages, '`^`' is the operator for a bitwise exclusive-or (a "XOR").

When writing mathematics in ASCII, it is customary to denotes exponentiation with the '`^`' character -- and it is not a XOR at all ! This notation comes from LaTeX, a typesetting system which is the de facto standard among mathematicians. In this message, I can use HTML tags and write '*g<sup>a</sup>*' to say "*g* to the power *a*", but if I were to write in plain ASCII (e.g. on Usenet), I would have to write: '*g^a*'.

Moreover, Diffie-Hellman uses *modular* exponentation on big integers -- typical size being 1024 bits or more. 32-bit or 64-bit integers will not be enough to achieve any kind of security, and, in any case, modular exponentiation is *not* what `pow()` implements (in algebraic terms, you want to work over a finite field, not plain integers or real numbers). In C# (.NET 4.0), you would want to use the [System.Numerics.BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) class, and in particular its `ModPow()` method. But first, if you ever want to do that, you first have to understand the underlying mathematics. You can begin by reading the first three chapters of the [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://www.cacr.math.uwaterloo.ca/hac/) (no relation whatsoever with Schneier's "Applied Cryptography", and, in my view, the "Handbook" is a far more useful book). It may seem a bit harsh, but you cannot hope to implement Diffie-Hellman properly unless you master the mathematics described in those first three chapters.

(And, of course, implementing cryptographic algorithms has other pitfalls, related to side-channel leaks, so even if you *do* understand what happens mathematically, making your own implementation is not necessarily a good idea.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I used this code from somebody else which I made it to work, but as I am not a cryptology nor mathematical expert I needed somebody to look at this.

I got the original source for this guy, but because I saw the change in XOR and POW I decided to ask the real experts. http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/security/TheDiffieHellmanKeyAgreementStandard.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Diffie-Hellman is based on modular exponentiation, so by using a different function in this code you haven't implemented Diffie-Hellman at all but something else.

Also the 63/64-bit numbers you're using are too small in any case.

You should read a basic text on cryptography, e.g. Schneier's Applied Cryptography.